# $f,g$ coincide on $\mathbb N$ iff $f(x)=g(x)$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a measure space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal P(\Bbb R), \mu_\Bbb N)$  where $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ denotes the power set of $\Bbb R$ and $\mu_\Bbb N$ is defined by $\mu_\Bbb N(A)= \vert {A \cap \Bbb N}\vert$= quantity of natural numbers in $A$,

how can I show that two functions $f,g:\Bbb R \to \mathbb R$ coincide on $\mathbb N$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)$ $\mu_\mathbb N$-almost everywhere?

The "$\Leftarrow$" implication is obvious and for the other direction I think proof by contraposition is the way to go?

Comment: How do you interpret "$\Leftarrow$"?

Comment: @Jack If they are equal $\mu_\mathbb N$ almost everywhere surely they are equal on $\mathbb N$, as every subset of $\mathbb N$ has non-zero $\mu_\mathbb N$ measure?

Comment: @Ant: Fair enough, I thought the other direction is much more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward implication should also be straightforward. Suppose $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be the set on which $f$ and $g$ differ. What is the $\mu_\mathbb{N}$ measure of $A$?

Comment: $\mu_\Bbb N (A)= \vert \{a \in \mathbb R : f(a) \neq g(a)$  and $a \in \Bbb N\} \vert = 0$

?

Comment: @Sigma Exactly. So $f$ and $g$ agree $\mu_\mathbb{N}$-a.e.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)\neq g(x)\}$. Then $f=g$ $\mu_\mathbb{N}$-a.e. if and only if 
$$
\mu_{\mathbb N}(A)=0
$$
if and only if
$$
\#(A\cap\mathbb{N})=0.
$$
Now, interpreting $
\#(A\cap\mathbb{N})=0
$ in words gives the proof.